# Which version of pysyft works with torch 1.8 or 1.9?

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

Which version of pysyft works with torch 1.8 or 1.9?

I have tried to install pysyft using following code

```
!pip install syft
!pip install syft_proto
```

This version install old of torch. I want pysyft to install latest version of torch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current latest version of `syft` [declares](https://github.com/OpenMined/PySyft/blob/0521f407cfdd046d00c332b733894a865848bd19/packages/syft/setup.cfg#L27) compatibility with `torch` <= 1.8.1. Just install the latest `syft`:

```
!pip install --upgrade --upgrade-strategy=eager syft
```

Comment: How can I hook torch with this version of syft. I want to hook torch in the following way                      `import syft as sy 
hook = sy.TorchHook(torch)                                                                                                   bob = sy.VirtualWorker(hook, id="bob")  
alice = sy.VirtualWorker(hook, id="alice") 
`                                                                                                                                                                          I am receiving an error that syft has no modeule TorchHook

Comment: @Hizafa `TorchHook` was removed in [commit 1ad898bd8](https://github.com/OpenMined/PySyft/commit/1ad898bd8). So you need a version of Syft before that. In [commit 782d59110](https://github.com/OpenMined/PySyft/commit/782d59110) the version is [0.2.6](https://github.com/OpenMined/PySyft/blob/782d591102e50cbb851a8cf9aa0e2faa8dd34906/setup.py#L40). So you should start with `!pip install syft==0.2.6`. Unfortunately that version requires Torch 1.4. So either you use old Syft with old Torch or you use the latest Syft with Torch 1.8.1 but without `TorchHook`.